# Trouble modelling a sports league in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

First time using Active Record. I'm looking to build a small online-simulation game where I have free agency, players, teams, a season and postseason schedule. Players should move from team to team and "compete" against each other. The problem I'm having is with backtrace errors when I attempt to link all of these classes together.  Here is the structure I have at the moment:

Schema:

```
create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "visiting_team"
  t.integer "home_team"
  t.integer "visiting_score"
  t.integer "home_score"
  t.integer "winner"
end

create_table "league", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "schedule"
  t.string "teams"
  t.string "players"
end

create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "position"
  t.integer  "rating"
  t.integer  "age"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "team_id"
  t.boolean  "free_agent"
end

create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "game"
end

create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "location"
  t.integer  "wins"
  t.integer  "losses"
  t.integer  "rating"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

And here are the relations:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many(:players)
  has_many(:games)
  belongs_to(:league)
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many(:games)
  belongs_to(:league)
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to(:team)
  has_many(:games)
  belongs_to(:league)
end

class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one(:schedule)
  has_many(:teams)
  has_many(:players)
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to(:teams)
  belongs_to(:players)
  belongs_to(:schedules)
end
```

Question: do I need to add foreign key relationships between league and players/teams for instance?  The documentation says not, but I don't understand how a player can belong to a league without references a primary/foreign key. Also, I'm unsure of how to structure the schedule class.  I'm not sure what attributes make sense. I want to each team to be able to compete in many games and a schedule to be able to be generated for each of them.  I'm a novice, so even pointing out good resources for activerecord (apart from the docs which I'm read although not understood completely) would be very helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: Documentation is saying that you don't need foreign_key constraint, you still need the column with related object id though.

Comment: Ok, that would explain why the players-teams relationship worked originally because of :team_id. Thanks

Comment: Now regarding schedule model - it doesn't seem necessary to have it. It is just a collection of games, right? So `league.games` is actually the whole schedule for this league.

Comment: You're right - I'll remove it.